# chrome inspector showing flashing on body tag

Tags: google-chrome

I can see in the inspector that the body tag is constantly flashing.  I think this happens when the dom is manipulated so when the page is first loaded, all elements flash purple once then settle.  For some reason my body tag remains flashing purple indicating it is still being updated.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Like an idiot I forgot I had a slider on the page....constantly updating the dom.

:D