# In the console, if the html tag flashes purple, does that mean it is being rerendered in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom

I am trying to fix a bug, but I am not sure if I should look for it in javascript. Or, should I look for it in css code. By minimizing the browser, less content shows, and the tag in the console flashes purple.

My question is entirely different from [chrome inspector showing flashing on body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645706/chrome-inspector-showing-flashing-on-body-tag). This post is not even a question, and people upvoted it. The post does not address why html tags flash purple, but only that it's problem can be fix by not moving the slider. I am asking for the reason why it is updating. If you think the question is bad, please explain why?

[image: Purple highlighted tag]

Comment: Please add more context of what it is that you're trying to do here.

Comment: Possibly yes. Or it could be a responsive CSS rule being applied. Check the source code of the page. Use the JS debugger. Inspect the relevant element to see what CSS rules are being applied.

Comment: I cant show what I am working on because it is corporate code. Is it really necessary to know what I am working on to answer the question?

Comment: @RahmiPruitt Context *frequently* matters a great deal, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a dev tools feature (which exists on both Chrome and Firefox). It indicates that something has updated inside that DOM element. The same can be seen on attributes if you modify them with JavaScript.

[Here's a similar question](https://superuser.com/q/988661), which for some odd reason is over at SuperUser, showing this behavior. There you can see the attributes highlighted, which causes its `<div>` to flash, as well as `<body>`.