# Edge developer tools - what does a flashing blue element mean?

Tags: web-scraping, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a web scraper, and am examining some dynamic content. In the Elements inspector, the `time` class is pulsing blue. I can't find any documentation on what this is. Obviously it is being periodically updated. Is there a way to find out how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means the element is dynamically changed. It seems that there's no document about this, but we can draw this conclusion based on experience.

You can also refer to this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402229/in-the-console-if-the-html-tag-flashes-purple-does-that-mean-it-is-being-reren). Edge is based on chromium, so it's the same in Edge developer tools.

Comment: Hi @GoldenJoe I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.